# in react hooks, onChange not firing if the user select the same value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-dom

here is my code

```
function SelectBugDemo(){
  var [value,set_value]=React.useState('one')
  var [count,set_count]=React.useState(1)
  
  function render_option(x){
      return <option key={x} value={x}>{x}</option>
  }    
  function onChange(event){
      console.log('onChange')//some side effect here
      set_value(event.target.value)
      set_count(x=>x+1)
  }    
  return <>{count}<select {...{onChange,value}}> {['one','two'].map(render_option)}</select></>
}
```

the problem is the onChange doesn't  get called if the user select the same value. I added the count to demonstrate the problem - it is incremented when selecting a different value, but not when selecting the same value.

is there any way to capture user selection of the same value? I tried onSelect, but it didn't work

Comment: try `onClick` because `onChange` is fired only when the value has changed

Comment: @Youssef i tries onClick. it generated too many events -  I just need one per selection

Comment: put `onClick` on `option` tag not on `select`

Comment: onClick is not supported with option tag unfortunately.

Comment: indeed, I just tried onClick on the option, but it did not fire at all

Comment: but why you want to fire an action when the user don't change the value ?

Answer (score 0):

`onChange` is triggered only when the value is changed.

**Try adding an `onBlur` to your select**.

```js
<select  onChange={onChange} onBlur={onChange} value={value}>
```

Comment: i just tried it, and gets fired when clicking outside the select, but not when selecting the same value